# Remote Desktop connection breaks the wireless connection

Tags: wireless-networking, remote-desktop, windows-8

When I connect to my Windows 8 Professional machine via Remote Desktop (RDP) I almost always get my WiFi connection broken.

The setup:

T61P Lenovo Laptop + W8 at home
Wireless Router with NAT forwards connections to that machine
Windows 7 laptop at work connecting to the home laptop

When I connect, very often I get to login and suddenly connection is lost and I cannot reconnect again. When I get home I find my WiFi connection is still connected to the Access Point but does not function. Can't even ping the router.

What is strange is that disabling wireless with the hardware switch and enabling it again doesn't help. 
The only way to make it works again:
 - Reboot
 - Disable wifi with hardware switch AND disable the network card in Device Manager, then enable both

I did not have this problem on the very same laptop when it was running Windows 7.

Any hint how can I find where the problem is?

Comment: Could you try disabling the firewall in Windows 8?  Perhaps it has decided the router is attacking it and has blocked connections from it.

Comment: Check that you have the latest wireless drivers for your device.

Answer (score 1):

Try the following suggestions:

- Install all the latest drivers from the Lenevo's website. (esp. network and graphics drivers)
- Install all Windows updates
- Disable firewall
- Close all network-related apps and check if the issue persists. If it doesn't maybe some app might be the cause.
- Upgrade the router's firmware
- If none of these suggestions work, do a clean install.

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the same problem where RDC would connect but would immediately turn black and would not allow re connection. Interestingly enough pinging the target rdc server would also timeout at the same time

To resolve my issue I had to remove the network wifi profile from the computer running rdc server, and then re-add it. Once it re-added it all worked without problem.